# compare files and storing similar data into different files

Tags: regex, string, perl

```
**LIST.txt**
lambo
audi
bmw
merc
ferrari
```

LIST is the file containing the names of cars and DETAILS is the file having the details of the cars named in LIST.txt

```
**DETAILS.txt**
lambo_1 gallardo lp570
lambo_2 aventador lp700
lambo_3 reventon lp640
audi_1 R8 V10
audi_2 A8 diesel 
bmw_1 Z4 blue
bmw_2 M3 red
bmw_3 328i black
merc_1 slr mclaran
merc_2 sls wings
```

I want to seperate the details of each car into different files i.e. i want 4 files in this case with lambo,audi,bmw and merc details in different files like file_1.txt , file_2.txt , file_3.txt and file_4.txt

```
file_1.txt
 lambo_1 gallardo lp570
    lambo_2 aventador lp700
    lambo_3 reventon lp640
```

similary other files as well

I am new to perl and i want your help.. I tried doing this by searching each element and storing it into a file (counter to change the file name) but i am not getting the expected result. so can anyone help me out.

```
  use strict;
  use warnings;    
  my $counter;    
  open  my $fh, "<", "F1.txt" or die $!;  
  open  my $fh1, "<", "F2.txt" or die $!;    
  my @b = <$fh>;  my @a = <$fh1>;
  for (@b)  
  {        
    my $line1 = $_;         
    for (@a)        
    {              
      $line2 = $_;              
      if ($line1 =~ /^$line2$/)              
      {        
        $counter++;                    
        open my $outfile, ">>", "A_${counter}.txt";                    
        print $outfile $line2;                    
        close $outfile;              
      }   
    } 
  }
```

I am trying to do something like this but it doesnt provide me a proper answer as required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic exercise in multiplexing. We even have an example in [Intermediate Perl](http://www.intermediateperl.com) (and the print version hit the shelves today).

You can open a bunch of write filehandles, one per car type, store them in a hash, then lookup the one you need when you run into it. This has the advantage of scanning the details once, unlike the other answers that scan it multiple times (as well as reading the entire thing into memory).

The first part uses [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) to create the hash of output file handles based on the cars in *list.txt*:

```
use v5.14;

my %out_fhs = do {
    open my $list_fh, '<', 'list.txt' or die;
    map { 
        state $n = 0;
        $n++;
        chomp;
        open my $fh, '>', "file_$n.txt" or die;
        ( $_, $fh )
        } <$list_fh>;
    };
```

The second part goes through *details.txt*, using the hash of filehandles you just created:

```
open my $details_fh, '<', 'details.txt' or die;

DETAIL: while( <$details_fh> ) {
    chomp;
    my( $car ) = m/\A(.*?)_/;
    my $fh = $out_fhs{ $car } || do {
        warn "Car [$car] is not in list.txt. Skipping.\n";
        next DETAIL;
        }

    say $fh $_;
    }
```

Comment: thank you @brain d foy will upgrade my version of Perl and try this on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %cars;
open my $fh, '<', 'F1.txt' or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    $cars{lc $_} = undef;
}
close $fh;

open $fh, '<', 'F2.txt' or die $!;
my $num = 1;
while (<$fh>) {
    if (/\s*([a-z]+)_\d+/i) {
        my $k = lc $1;
        if (exists $cars{$k}) {
            if (!defined $cars{$k}) {
                open my $fd, '>', "file_$num.txt" or die $!;
                $cars{$k} = $fd;
                $num++;
            }
            print {$cars{$k}} $_;
        }
    }
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer @cdtits but the files are generated and they all are empty... i want to know the line which prints the details into the generated files???

Comment: @unkaitha: print {$cars{$1}} $_; and you must "use strict;" to print result to each file.

Comment: @unkaitha: case-sensitive? convert it to lower now

Comment: @unkaitha: it works fine at my machine. you may use print to debug yourself?

Comment: @unkaitha: try uncomment the print line?

Comment: @unkaitha: create files that have cars only now

Comment: thank you for the modification in the code but now its not generating the file also.. what am i supposed to do????

Comment: @cdtits: Can u help me out in this question of mine.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242557/input-to-the-program-with-all-the-strings-in-an-array-one-by-one

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option that generates file_audi.txt, etc:

```
use Modern::Perl;

{
    open my $DETAILSIn, '<', 'DETAILS.txt' or die $!;
    my @details = <$DETAILSIn>;

    open my $LISTIn, '<', 'LIST.txt' or die $!;
    while ( my $car = <$LISTIn> ) {
        chomp $car;
        my @recs = grep /^$car\_/i, @details or next;
        open my $fh, '>', "file_$car.txt" or die $!;
        print $fh @recs;
    }
}
```

All open files will automatically close when their handles fall out of scope.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @kenosis.. is their a way to do it without the modules???  i am trying to install these modules but i am not successful in doing so.

Comment: @unkaitha - The above will run w/o the `use Modern::Perl;` pragma, which includes `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.  However, it's best to include, at least, the latter two pragmas in your scripts.

Comment: ya i used strict and warnings and even then it didnt generate any file.

Comment: @unkaitha - Am unsure what issue you're encountering, as the files are generated on my system, in the directory where DETAILS.txt and LIST.txt are.  From your last comment, I notice that you had the same issue with cdtits' script.